# Macport install stucked at "==> making install in src/darwintracelib1.0..."

Tags: ios, installation, macports

I am running "sudo make install" on Macport from the source, but it stuck at "==> making install in src/darwintracelib1.0 ... -c -o access.o access.c". I tried to reboot, but it stayed the same situation.

I am using Macbook air, OS X 10.9.5 (13F34), Xcode 4.6 (the highest version I could use).

Is that possible that anyone could tell me what should I do? Thank you very much.

Comment: Odd that you are compiling during `make install`.  Did you forget to `make` before it?  Regardless, you should take a spindump of the compiler process and file a radar at `http://bugreport.apple.com` if the issue still exists in newer tools.  You might want to try using clang-3.7 from MacPorts.

Comment: I wrote that file, but I'm not going to be able to help with a complete log of the build output. Additionally, what Jeremy said.